# Отладка выполнения программы в DOSBOX

Tags: ассемблер

Всем привет. Дело такое, у меня задание в универе по языку ассемблер. Задание: Х= 3(А - 2В) +50 – С / 2 , в программе я задал такие значения: a = 10 ,b = 20 ,c = 5,x = ?
Код программы:

```
data segment
   a dw 10
   b dw 20
   c dw 5
   x dw ?

data ends

code segment
    assume cs:code, ds:data

start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, a      ; AX = A
    sub ax, b      ; AX = A - B
    sub ax, b      ; AX = A - 2B
    add ax, ax     ; AX = 2A - 4B
    add ax, ax     ; AX = 4A - 8B
    sub ax, bx     ; AX = 4A - 8B - BX
    add ax, ax     ; AX = 8A - 16B - 2BX
    add ax, 50     ; AX = 8A - 16B - 2BX + 50
    mov bx, 2      ; BX = 2
    mov cx, c      ; CX = C
    shr cx, 1      ; CX = C / 2
    sub ax, cx     ; AX = 8A - 16B - 2BX + 50 - C/2

    mov x, ax      ; сохранить результат в переменную X
quit:
    mov ax, 4C00h  ; завершить программу
    int 21h
code ends

end start
```

Теперь ,проблема. Я не могу найти в DOSBOX результат, т.е x. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Я знаю,что результат представлен в 16-тиричной системе, и чтобы получить его в десятичную ,мне надо отнять от него FFFF и 1, полученное значение перевести в десятиричную и должно получится -42.5 по идее)

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос. Исколесил весь интернет,не нашел нормальную информацию по DOSBOX.

Comment: Нужно собрать com либо exe, а потом открывать turbodebuger. DOSBOX - это просто окно, которое поддерживает запуск, программа которую запускате, скорее всего turbodebugger. Нудно открыть собранный модуль и начать трассировку f7. Тогда увидите ваш код и значение регистров.

Comment: @nick_n_a все подготовил,собрал exe,программа выполнилась успешно,просто не знаю ,как результат посмотреть

Comment: В данном случае резултьтат вы никуда не выводите, нажимайте F7 пока не дойдёте до инструкции `mov ax, 4C00h` её не выполняйте, результат будет в AX в hex (можно калькулятором перевести в dec на вкладке програмист). Для вывода результата куда либо программу нужно допиливать ещё.

Comment: @nick_n_a , мои одногруппники в отчетах как то находили эти результаты в окне cpu.

Comment: @nick_n_a щас попробую

Comment: Да, верно, `ax 0192` который у вас на скрине дублирует окно CPU? Именно тут ax будет содержать результат когда он готов, но ещё не стерт инструкцией `mov ax, 4C00h`

Comment: @nick_n_a на скрине там не понятно что отображается, и в этот раз ,я 2 раза так сделал, разные числа получились и очень большие после перевода в десятичную систему 50000 c чем то,например

Comment: Чему равно AX BX CX у вас, когда доходите до quit? Что бы я понимал что вы там где надо, или добавляйте ещё скрин, что бы было понятно что программу вы выполнили нормально. Может у вас и правильный результат, мне это не понятно. Если AX BX CX соответствуют расчётным то всё нормально, покажите их

Comment: @nick_n_a . Клавишей f7 хожу по строчкам программы ,дохожу до строчки перед quit. Делал так раза 3 (после каждого раза перезапускал dosbox) и выподали разные значения. Конкретно щас : AX=C83C BX=0002 CX = 0002

Comment: @nick_n_a ,перезапустил,теперь значение у ax = f4de

Comment: BX правильно (в конце), СX правильно. AX нет, у вас ошибка в программе. В excel если посчитать - можно найти ошибку

Comment: Вы используете bx неприсвоенную, `sub ax, bx     ; AX = 4A - 8B - BX`  BX  тут содержит мусор, она и портит результат.

Comment: Трассировкой F7 такое легко ищется, просто считаете результат на бумаге на каждом шаге и сравниваете с тем что на экране.

Comment: Да, и тут задача с подвохом, у вас ответ будет отрицательный, т.е. FFD6 правильный ответ что соответствует -42, мог ошибится на еденицу (FFD7 -41 или FFD5 -43) потому что целочисленная арифметика дробную часть отбрасывает.

Comment: @nick_n_a ,спасибо вам большое. Проблема действительно в коде. И спасибо за то,что научили находить результат в такого рода программах!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. На скрине отладчик td.exe borland turbo debugger, одна из более менее удобных программ для отладки на ассемблере. Т.к. программа довольно старая, под winxp x86 и ранее она работает и так, под современной виндой она работает через DosBox
2. Результат виден сразу после выполнения программы в правом окне светятся регистры ax 0192 bx 0531 и т д (ax bx cx dx di di bp sp ds es ss sp ip). Для выполнения программы по шагам используем F7

Начинаем выполнение (нажимаем F7 и смотрим регистры), для перехода к следующему шагу нажимаем F7 ещё раз и ещё раз:

```
; a = 10    b = 20  c = 5
; ax мусор bx мусор сx мусор
mov ax, a      ; AX = A
; ax 000A bx мусор сx мусор
sub ax, b      ; AX = A - B
; ax FFF6 (-10)  bx мусор сx мусор
sub ax, b      ; AX = A - 2B
; ax FFE2 (-30)   bx мусор сx мусор
add ax, ax     ; AX = 2A - 4B
; ax FFC4 (-60)  bx мусор сx мусор
add ax, ax     ; AX = 4A - 8B
; ax FF88 (-120) bx мусор сx мусор
sub ax, bx     ; AX = 4A - 8B - BX
; ax мусор       bx мусор сx мусор
```

Кажется дальше нет смысла трассировать, нужно править ошибки.

Тут задача с подвохом, целочисленная арифметика не считает дроби. какоето_число - 2.5 = -42.5 так не будет, будет какоето_число - 2 = -43 т.е. FFD5. Проще всего перевести - калькулятор (calc.exe) вид программист, забиваем -43, переводим в hex и лишние "F" убираем.  Результат в регистрах будет актуален с момента получения результата до момента перетирания его другим числом, т.е. в точке останова "quit".